# Getting an error when trying to use a one line if statement in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement

I am getting an error when trying to use an one line if statement in Unity. I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Here is the line:
`MyImage.color == Color.white ? MyImage.color = Color.green : MyImage.color = Color.white;`

I have it in the Update function. It's all that is in the update function. It says only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. I am assigning a color to an image so I'm not sure what is wrong. This is unity 2018.3.0f3 if that matters.

Answer (score 4):

the correct way should be like this:

```c#
MyImage.color = (MyImage.color == Color.white) ? Color.green : Color.white;
```

Comment: The `( )` are redundant, though

Comment: I tried to make it readable and easy to understand, instead of long explanation.
and agree, it's not necessary to have "( )".

Comment: Oh if you have one please add a long explanation! we want quality posts here and the more valid information the better ;)

Comment: it's already very clean and readable. it's good enough to solve the problem without pages of theory, which are not necessary.

Comment: well more or less ... currently it is a code snippet that eventually works ... but what exactly the original issue was is not totally cleared here (`only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` .. apparently OP didn't understand what this message really means)

Comment: Interesting, it depends on what people is looking for. I simply provide a working solution because I think that he had syntax error. In this case, I don’t understand the point of explaining in long story...